# SSJS unable to Parse JSON using the Platform Script.Util.HttpRequest

Tags: json, ssjs, cloudpage, marketing-cloud

For a cloud page, I have a use case, where using the Script.Util.HttpRequest/Response I get the OAuth token.

Then I have another request, the response structure of which looks like below:

```
{
  "requestId": "xyz",
  "definitions": [
    {
      "definitionKey": "account-reset"
    },
    {
      "definitionKey": "account-submit"
    }
  ],
  "count": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pageSize": 10
}
```

I am getting the response, however, the response string length is always 15 chars -> should be more and the Platform.Function.ParseJSON returns null.

Greatly appreciate any help and some sample code. I don't want to use the HTTP.Get and HTTP.Post unless they are the last resort. Below is my code snippet causing the issue.

```
var resp = req.send();// this is the Script.Util function for HTTP Send
var resultString = resp.content;
var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(resultString);
```

Comment: What happens when you wrap the parsing in a try/catch?

Comment: When I put it in try catch, this is the error it is showing: `{"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Script.Util returns in a CLR format which does not translate well to SSJS. You need to first turn this CLR object to a string format via `String()` then use `ParseJSON()` to turn it back into an object as a JSON for you to utilize and parse through.

E.g.

```
Var myObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resp.content))
```

For more info see my blog article [here](https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/) or a video I did on it [here](https://youtu.be/zzbR0az63Y0).

Comment: I did the following: `var resp = req.send(); var resultString = String(resp.content); var respJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(resultString); // this no longer gives an exception but the 'respJSON' is blank`

Comment: I added the following lines of code

 `var content = resp.content; 
var contentType = resp.contentType;
var encoding = resp.encoding;
var status = resp.returnStatus;
var code = resp.statusCode;`. 

The results are as follows: 

`{
"requestId": "aef43135","definitions": [
    {
      "definitionKey": "2caf3954",
      "createdDate": "2020-12-22T15:41:00",
      "modifiedDate": "2020-12-22T16:16:00"
    }
  ],
  "page": 1,
  "pageSize": 50
}
contentType : application/json; charset=UTF-8
Encoding :
status : 0
code : undefined`

All I need is "definitionKey"

Comment: I printed each variable above using the "Write" function

Comment: Sorry, one more comment - Is there a way that we get the values from SSJS and then use the browser side JS libraries like `underscore.js` or something to parse the SSJS JSON response. Maybe use a dummy DE to write the JSON response and later use underscore.js to parse the JSON. I don't know how the code might look like but is there such an option. And I want all of this to happen when the cloud page loads

Comment: what you provided for 'definitions' is not a valid JSON, so if this is an accurate representation of your return, that could be causing an issue. Can you edit your question to include what you are currently doing and the expected response to allow for easier viewing?

Comment: As far as parsing via clientside JS, this can be done, but it has to be done clientside by passing that value to client-side JS. It cannot happen prior to page load like what happens with SSJS and as it is client-side, all of it is fully visible to the end user.

Comment: you can try to recreate the libraries that are used e.g. `underscore.js` but these tend to use scripting above ECMA 3, which means that you would need to do a lot of editing and backfilling to get it to work correctly in SFMC SSJS.

Comment: I ended up parsing the string from resp.content using a JS function. Nothing else seemed to work.

I am building a UI for this Transactional SMS Messaging API
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getSMSDefinitions.htm

Answer (score 0):

Response from `Script.Util` is not a string and that causes `Platform.Function.ParseJSON()` to fail. Wrap it with `String()` and it will work.

```
var resultJSON = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(String(resultString));
```